# MSI installer All User : Set value for SCRNSAVE.EXE

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

On my WPF program with MSI Installer, i need to set up HKCU\SCRNSAVE.EXE (and also ScreenSaveTimeOut, ScreenSaveActive and ScreenSaverIsSecure) registry key.

The problem is when i try to insert all this keys on registry via my MSI installer project (set to ALL User), my installer not create the keys.

I already try to install this key on HKLM but the configuration not apply on Windows.

Does there is a way to do this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to write registry in custom action of MSI installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524088/unable-to-write-registry-in-custom-action-of-msi-installer)

Comment: The problem was not the same, in my case, the truble was causing by the all user install. With this option, the installer cannont access to the HKCU registrykey :(

I found a solution by add the key when my program start, but when i start the program with my installer (after the install), it's always in admin mode and it's not working too. It's only working when the program is launch by the user manualy

Comment: You need to look into Active Setup or creating an advertised shortcut to your application and writing HKCU that way.  In any case, you shouldn't be writing registry values like HKCU\SCRNSAVE.EXE?

Comment: @JordanFavray the outcome that you describe sounds like a best practice actually. It is much better the installer will only deal with copying and what to copy and leave it to the app to set the configurations on 1st run. It will force you to develop your program to be much resilient and will ease the installer role.

Comment: My app is a screensaver with a systray application ;-) This is why i need to write to HKCU\SCRNSAVE.EXE

Comment: You mean HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\SCRNSAVE.EXE?

Comment: Yes of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution !

I loop into HKEY_USERS to add my registry key as i needed :)

```
RegistryKey lUsersKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.Users, RegistryView.Registry64);

foreach (string lUsersSubKey in lUsersKey.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey lDesktopKey = lUsersKey.OpenSubKey(lUsersSubKey, true).CreateSubKey("Control Panel\\Desktop", true);
        lDesktopKey.SetValue("SCRNSAVE.EXE", myScrPath);
    }
    catch
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.  That would only work for users that had logged into the machine already wouldn't it?  You should still probably look at Active Setup for subsequent users that log on....

Comment: Work on new users too because the key is set too HKU/Default So new user will have this key too

Comment: WARNING: HKU/.Defaul tis not a default registry for new user profiles, it's a registry for the ADMIN/System account